# Post request in laravel8 not functioning

Tags: post, laravel-8, rest

Get request is working fine. But when i try to create a post through POST request it's giving the following error....

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'title' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `posts` (`title`, `content`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, 2021-03-22 06:05:00, 2021-03-22 06:05:00))
```

Here is my database table name: id title content created_at

Post model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table="posts";

    protected $fillable=[

        "title",
        "content"
    ];

};
```

database:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('content');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

api route:

```
    Route::get('/posts', function(){

    return Post::all();
});

Route::post('/posts', function(){
    
return Post::create([

 "title" => request('title'),
 "content" => request('content'),
 ]);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check if you're receiving correct data from request() method

```
Route::post('/posts', function(){
   dd(request('title'));
```

The other way you can try it is

```
Route::post('/posts', function(Request $request){
    
return Post::create([

 "title" => $request->get('title'),
 "content" => $request->get('content'),
 ]);

});
```

Greetings